# Syntax/notation for gb in openshift inventory file?

Tags: openshift

I am creating an OpenShift 3.11 Cluster and found in the docs different information on how to specify gb. I need to restrict memory for logging-es (elasticsearch) and I am not sure which notation is the correct one:

1. openshift_logging_es_memory_limit=2Gi
2. openshift_logging_es_memory_limit=2G

I use the following docs [site](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/configuring_inventory_file.html)

Most notations show `xxx=2Gi` while the notation under [this documentation page](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/configuring_inventory_file.html#advanced-installation-logging-storage) shows at one specific point:

```
xxx=1G
```

I like to think that this is typo, but I want to make sure that it is one.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. A good question should be "crisp" and that doesn't include adding anything non-relevant, so leave out thanks, greeting etc. Also make sure all tags are relevant to your question, that excludes generics that are valid for all posts relevant to `openshift`  like  `ascii` or `utf-8` or that are not otherwise  tag definition related like `yaml` (hover over the tag to see the description which should indicate to you when it is applicable and when not)

Comment: uff thanks for the info. I will reconsider asking questions on stack overflow :-D This seems to rigid for my personal preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G stands for Gigabyte. Gi stands for Gibibyte. They're just2 different ways to specify byte requirements. Gi being a base 2 value, 1 GiB equals 2^30 bytes or 1,073,741,824 bytes. G being a base 10 value, 1 GB equals 10^9 bytes or 1,000,000,000 bytes.

Gi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte
G: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte

From the Kubernetes docs (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#meaning-of-memory)

> You can express memory as a plain integer or as a fixed-point integer using one of these suffixes: E, P, T, G, M, K. You can also use the power-of-two equivalents: Ei, Pi, Ti, Gi, Mi, Ki. For example, the following represent roughly the same value:

```
128974848, 129e6, 129M, 123Mi
```

Comment: Are you sure that this notation for openshift inventory is correct and specifies Gibi vs Giga? Im used to a Gib or GiB notation for Gibibyte. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Yes, the Kubernetes docs adds some additional info: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#meaning-of-memory